# Comprehension list in Keras backend for custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am trying to implement a custom loss function in Keras.

I wrote my custom loss function in "standard" python/numpy before realizing that it needs to be in Tensorflow/Keras backend. I saw that some simple functions such as mean or sum are implemented in the Keras backend and thus I tried to translate them. However, I have no idea how to translate comprehension lists or cdist function that I use below.

The original lines in python/numpy are the ones that are commented, the non-commented lines are the lines I tried to write using keras backend:

```
def loss_zhang(y_true, y_pred):

    predictions = y_pred[0]
    features = y_pred[1]

    # Parameter ~ hypersphere radius
    m = 0.5

    # Find the center of the features for the reference class
    # center = np.mean(features[np.where(y_true==1)], axis=0)
    center = K.mean(features[K.tf.where(y_true==1)], axis=0)

    # Compute the distances between all the features and the center
    # dist = cdist(features, [center], metric='euclidean')
    dist = [K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(u - center), axis=-1)) for u in features]

    # Compute the loss for each sample (based on distance to center)
    # losses = [ofRef*d**2 + (1-ofRef)*(np.max([0, m-d]))**2 for d, ofRef in zip(dist, y_true)]
    losses = y_true*K.square(dist) + (1-y_true)*K.square(K.max([0, m-d]))

    # Total loss = sum of individual losses
    # return 0.5*np.sum(losses)
    return 0.5*K.sum(losses)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
y_true = y_true[0]
predictions = y_pred[0]
features = y_pred[1]

# Parameter ~ hypersphere radius
m = K.constant(0.35)

# Find the center of the features for the reference class
center = tf.reduce_mean(tf.gather_nd(features, K.tf.where(tf.squeeze (tf.equal(y_true, 1)))), axis=0)

# Compute the distances between all the features and the center
dist = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(features - center), axis=-1))

# Compute the loss for each sample (based on distance to center)
losses = y_true*K.square(dist) + (1-y_true)*K.square(tf.maximum(0., m-dist))

return 0.5*K.sum(losses)
```